# How does Green's theorem apply here?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Let $D$ be the region delimited by 
$$\partial D:
\begin{cases}
C_1: x^2 + y^2 = 5^2\\
C_2:(x-2)^2+y^2= 1\\
C_3:(x+2)^2+y^2 = 1\\
C_4: x^2+(y-2)^2= 1\\
C_5: x^2+(y+2)^2= 1
\end{cases}
$$
I've sketched this and the region looks like this (the inside of the big circle, intersection the outside of the small circles should be shaded): 
[image]

So the boundary of the region is not a closed curve... but I'm asked to verify Green's theorem for this region anyway. I don't understand how the theorem applies, could someone explain this?

E: From the comments it looks like I should do $$\iint_D (Q_x-P_y)dA=\oint_{C_1} Fds-\sum_{i\ge 2} \oint_{C_i}Fds$$

Is this correct? I don't see how this follows from Green's theorem's statement (using wikipedia for reference).

Comment: The boundary is a union of closed curves, so you'll take orientations on each of them (so that you have a consistent choice of inward/outward normal) and then the integral over the boundary will just be the sum of the integrals over each of those curves.

Comment: Do it for the large circle and smaller ones, then subtract.

Comment: @Neal Could you explain a bit why that works? I was intuitively going to do that, but I don't really understand why I should.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_multiple_boundary_components) has a good explanation of the technique and way to think about the multiple boundaries.

[This page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx) goes into more detail about **why** the technique works.